# How to properly proxy through nginx and pm2 a Server Rendering app with React Router

Tags: reactjs, nginx, pm2

Hello all I'm trying to deploy a test app on AWS EC2 instance using Server Rendering with React Router as per [this tutorial](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-server-rendering) for the server rendering component using nginx to proxy through to localhost:PORT as follows

nginx config:

```
server{ listen 80 ; listen [::]:80;

server_name myservername.com;

location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; }

}
```

pm2:

Simply running

```
 pm2 start /location --name AppName
```

I'm able to react my app but only the backend part of it, if I try to reach the frontend all of the paths seem to be redirected to the 404 handler of React Router, however if I was to start the app with the comand

```
 node server.js
```

It all works fine but of course that is not the way to do it since once the command line is killed then the process is killed. after webpack builds the production code it creates a build.js inside the public folder and it creates a server.js, from what I understand the server.js handles what to display or respond accordingly. I console log the path thinking maybe the path after the proxy is different well no it returns the path that I'm asking for, also found that maybe pm2 serves static files with

```
 pm2 serve /path/bundle.js port
```

so I did that with the same port as the back end I knew that would not work but figure give it a try. I've seen suggestions where you make nginx have a / path and a /api path but since its server rendered that does not work plus given the fact that the frontend and all css or html calls return 404 when using pm2 yet using the same nginx config file but running the server from the command line works tells me that nginx config file is good but maybe pm2 is the likely culprit, If anyone can help me figure out what I'm missing I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I finally figured it out, so pm2 was not able to hit some of the routes because the bundle front end is located in a different folder and its also static so the fix is to adjust your nginx config in the following form

```
server{ listen 80 ; listen [::]:80;

server_name myservername.com;

location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; }

}

location /bundle.js{
root /path/;
index bundle.js;
}
```

which now serves the files that are "out of reach"